# How can I take a JSON string output from `actions/github-script` action?

Tags: github-actions

I am using `actions/github-script` to write a script to load a JSON file from local and output the JSON content.

Below is the workflow file:

```yaml
name: test json

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  json-loader:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      app-config: ${{ steps.load-json.outputs.result }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: json
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        id: load-json
        with:
          result-encoding: string
          script: |
            try {
              const fs = require('fs')
              const jsonString = fs.readFileSync('./.github/workflows/config.json')
              console.log(`json string ${jsonString}`)
              return jsonString
            } catch(err) {
              core.error("Error while reading or parsing the JSON")
              core.setFailed(err)
            }

  output:
    needs: json-loader
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
          echo "${{ needs.json-loader.outputs.app-config }}"
```

The `config.json` file is:

```json
{
  "transaction": {
    "sonar": true,
    "build-image": "ubuntu-latest"
  },
  "site": {
    "sonar": true,
    "build-image": "ubuntu-latest"
  }
}
```

but I get an error in the `output` job:

```
{
/home/runner/work/_temp/6adeebad-5d50-4995-bd0c-7fcfe74aa37c.sh: line 3: transaction:: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

It says `transaction:: command not found`. But `transaction` is a key field in the JSON file. The `json-loader` job should return the JSON file as a string value. Why does it complain about `command not found`?

Comment: This is nothing to do with GitHub Actions, you'd get the same thing locally in bash. Also there's really no need to run a JS script just to echo a file to the job outputs (and note `jq` is already installed on the runner to manipulate JSON).